# Python - Plotting T_value above barplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is a minimal example, code, of what I am doing:

```
B = np.array([0.6383447, 0.5271385, 1.7721380, 1.7817880])
b_mean = mean(B)
ori_t = stats.ttest_1samp(B, 0)[0]
r1 = [1]
plt.bar(r1,b_mean,width=barWidth, color="blue")
```

This code produce a barplot of the mean of the 'B' array. Now I would like to add the T-value (extracted at the 3 line) and display it above the barplot. I tried the following:

```
plt.text(x=r1, y=b_mean+0.1, s=ori_t, size = 6)
```

each time it returns

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

which I don't understand. Does anyone knows how to achieve or overcome that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing `r1 = [1]` as the x-position for your text. `r1` is a list which cannot be used for specifying the position of the text. `x` and `y` arguments in `plt.text` should be scalars. So either you write `x=1` OR you write `x=r1[0]` both of which are scalars. I have included the missing imports in my answer to make it complete. I have also adjusted the y-limits accordingly.

From the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html):

> x, y : scalars
>   The position to place the text. By default, this is in data coordinates. The coordinate system can be changed using the transform parameter.

```
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

B = np.array([0.6383447, 0.5271385, 1.7721380, 1.7817880])
b_mean = np.mean(B)
ori_t = stats.ttest_1samp(B, 0)[0]

r1 = [1]
plt.bar(r1,b_mean,width=0.02, color="blue")

plt.text(x=r1[0], y=b_mean+0.1, s=ori_t, size = 10)
# plt.text(x=1, y=b_mean+0.1, s=ori_t, size = 10)
plt.ylim(0, b_mean+0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]